# OpenSL ES for recording audio in android NDK

Tags: java, android, audio, java-native-interface

I am starting to learn OpenSL ES for android, before I do I want to confirm if I record directly using JNI will it bypass manufacturer's pre-processing like AGC and low pass filtering? Will it provide raw PCM data source data?

Is most of the pre-processing done at the kernel driver level or at the library level?

Is there a way to get pure audio directly from drivers with JNI and does google or phone manufacturer's give this kind of access?

Comment: I find it very unlikely that you can bypass the audio HAL (AFAIK, any recording done with OpenSL ES on Android will use Android's native AudioRecord class internally). So to your question I'd say "No, it won't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very detail information about audio requirements for android device and application is connected to the device drivers. You will find information about the following [here](http://source.android.com/devices/audio.html)

1. Application framework
2. JNI
3. Native framework
4. Binder IPC
5. Media Server
6. HAL
7. Kernel Driver

Hope this helps to people.